# Como captuar todas as imagens de um campo imagem no XML para gravar no MYSQL?

Tags: php, xml

Boa Tarde!

Preciso capturar em PHP todas as imagens contidas no campo imagem do XML abaixo para gravar no MYSQL, como faço?

```
<Media>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973974.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973975.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973976.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973977.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973978.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973979.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973980.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973981.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973982.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973983.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973984.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973985.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973986.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973987.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973988.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973989.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973990.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973991.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973992.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973993.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973994.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973995.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973996.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973997.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973998.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21973999.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974000.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974001.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974002.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974003.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974004.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974005.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974006.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974007.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974008.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974009.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974010.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974011.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974012.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974013.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974014.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974015.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974016.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974017.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974018.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974019.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974020.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974021.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974022.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974023.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974024.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974025.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974026.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974027.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974028.jpg</Item>
<Item medium="image">http://teste.com.br/11772/21974029.jpg</Item>
</Media>
```

Aguardo ajuda!

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que significa gravar no mysql?

Comment: @durtto quero armazenar em uma variável e gravar todas as imagens no banco de dados.

Comment: Você quer gravar o arquivo da imagem ou a url da imagem?

Comment: @durtto a url da imagem. Mas isso é simples, preciso saber como capturar todas estas imagens.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias e várias maneiras.

A mais rápida para fazer, pelo menos para mim, seria usar o `preg_match_all()`, [leia sobre ele aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php).

Dessa forma seria:

```
preg_match_all('/<Item medium="image">(.*?)<\/Item>/', $texto, $url);
```

Isso retornaria uma array `$url` com todos os links, que estão entre as tags de `Item`.

*Este seria o retorno usando a função acima:*

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973974.jpg [1] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973975.jpg [2] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973976.jpg [3] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973977.jpg [4] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973978.jpg [5] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973979.jpg [6] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973980.jpg [7] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973981.jpg [8] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973982.jpg [9] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973983.jpg [10] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973984.jpg [11] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973985.jpg [12] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973986.jpg [13] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973987.jpg [14] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973988.jpg [15] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973989.jpg [16] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973990.jpg [17] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973991.jpg [18] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973992.jpg [19] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973993.jpg [20] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973994.jpg [21] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973995.jpg [22] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973996.jpg [23] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973997.jpg [24] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973998.jpg [25] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973999.jpg [26] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974000.jpg [27] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974001.jpg [28] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974002.jpg [29] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974003.jpg [30] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974004.jpg [31] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974005.jpg [32] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974006.jpg [33] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974007.jpg [34] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974008.jpg [35] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974009.jpg [36] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974010.jpg [37] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974011.jpg [38] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974012.jpg [39] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974013.jpg [40] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974014.jpg [41] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974015.jpg [42] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974016.jpg [43] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974017.jpg [44] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974018.jpg [45] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974019.jpg [46] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974020.jpg [47] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974021.jpg [48] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974022.jpg [49] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974023.jpg [50] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974024.jpg [51] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974025.jpg [52] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974026.jpg [53] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974027.jpg [54] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974028.jpg [55] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974029.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [0] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973974.jpg [1] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973975.jpg [2] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973976.jpg [3] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973977.jpg [4] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973978.jpg [5] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973979.jpg [6] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973980.jpg [7] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973981.jpg [8] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973982.jpg [9] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973983.jpg [10] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973984.jpg [11] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973985.jpg [12] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973986.jpg [13] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973987.jpg [14] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973988.jpg [15] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973989.jpg [16] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973990.jpg [17] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973991.jpg [18] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973992.jpg [19] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973993.jpg [20] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973994.jpg [21] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973995.jpg [22] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973996.jpg [23] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973997.jpg [24] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973998.jpg [25] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21973999.jpg [26] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974000.jpg [27] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974001.jpg [28] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974002.jpg [29] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974003.jpg [30] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974004.jpg [31] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974005.jpg [32] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974006.jpg [33] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974007.jpg [34] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974008.jpg [35] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974009.jpg [36] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974010.jpg [37] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974011.jpg [38] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974012.jpg [39] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974013.jpg [40] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974014.jpg [41] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974015.jpg [42] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974016.jpg [43] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974017.jpg [44] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974018.jpg [45] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974019.jpg [46] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974020.jpg [47] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974021.jpg [48] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974022.jpg [49] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974023.jpg [50] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974024.jpg [51] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974025.jpg [52] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974026.jpg [53] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974027.jpg [54] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974028.jpg [55] => http://teste.com.br/11772/21974029.jpg ) )
```

Portanto para obter os valores "separados" basta usar a própria array dita acima, obviamente. Usando `$url[1][0]`, por exemplo.

Você também pode fazer um `foreach` de `$url[1]`, assim para exibir cada link ou inserir ou unir para um INSERT. Enfim.

Comment: Manipular xml com regex O.o?

Comment: Ele só quer obter o link. Isso é uma saída. Não é ideal. Se quiser realmente aproveitar o XML você pode usar o aquele `simplexml` e fazer um loop com o `path` de itens, já inclusive respondi questões usando isso, mas não acho que seja rápido (para fazer) do que o regex. Mas se o XML tiver este padrão acho que não há problemas. Obvio, se houver várias "<media>", isso não vai servir, mas isso não foi mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se vc já teve a sua reposta, mas aqui vai uma solução a mais:

Use essa função para ler o seu arquivo xml e transformá-lo numa array php.
O arquivo xml pode ter qualquer estrutura. Não importa. A função vai gerar uma array php que vai ser um espelho do seu xml.
Fonte: [link](https://gist.github.com/igoralves1/82b7ff09632fcb9916a31842533f6bf6).

```
/*
This function goes to the directory $pathDir, pass trough each all files inside it,
seeks for any file that math to the $searchString and reads it.
Return the content of all matched xml files within a php Array.
Ex: 
We have inside the FTP the follow files genereted by a CronJob: 
fileCarAudiRent2015.xml, fileCarAudiRent2016.xml, fileCarAudiSell2015.xm,
fileCarBMWRent2015.xml, fileCarBMWSell2016.xml, fileBoatWMBRent2015.xml, fileBoatWMBSell2015.xml,
fileBoatAudiRent2015.xml, fileBoatAudiSell2016.xml, ... .

We want to grab the content of all files that matches "Boat" string.
So, we need to do like this:
$arrInfo = read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll("c:/Path_to_the_Folder","Boat");

We want to grab the content of all files that matches "Sell2015" string.
So, we need to do like this:
$arrInfo = read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll("c:/Path_to_the_Folder","Sell2015");

We should inprove this function to match criteria like:
Give me all that has Sell AND 2015
Give me all that has Sell OR 2015
...
Give me all that has BMW AND 2015
*/


public function read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll($pathDir,$searchString) {

$xml_array="";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($pathDir); //http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
  if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
      $fileName = $fileinfo->getFilename();
      //Macth rule
      $pos = strpos($fileName, $searchString);
      if ( $pos!== false) {//If match the sought string
        $filePath = $pathDir.$fileName;
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($filePath);
            $xml_array [] = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1)));  

           /* If needed 
           $invoice_date = $xml_array["Documents"]["InvoiceDate"];
           $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $invoice_date);//Formated date inside xml
           $year = $date->format('Y');//Desired output year
           $month = $date->format('M');//Desired output month 
           */

      }//End of if ( $pos!== false)                        
  } 
}
//Testing
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($xml_array);
echo "</pre>";


return $xml_array;

 }
```

Entáo a função aceita 2 parâmetros:

1. **$pathDir** = o caminho ate o FOLDER onde se encontram os arquivos xmls
2. **$searchString** = uma string para ser filtrada no nome dos arquivos.

Digamos que dentro do folder FTP_xmls vc tem diferentes arquivos xml. Vc quer somente os arquivos minhasfotosdoano.xml. Então a função entra nesse folder, e retorna uma array php com dados de todos os xmls que possuem "*fotos*" no nome.

```
$arrPHP =  read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll("c:/path/dir ...","fotos");
```

Agora vc tem uma array php com o que lhe interessa.
Voltando ao seu cõdigo, faça um loop nessa array e insira no Mysql as informações que vc deseja.

Vc tbm vai precisar filtrar a sua string antes de inserir no MySql, pois vc vai ter error se tentar sem o filtro.

Para isso use essa função dentro do seu loop.
Fonte: nesse [link](https://gist.github.com/igoralves1/9be2cdab5623bf790e590b69d0d12ef2).

```
private function tool_string_filter($str) {
    if(is_null($str)){
     return "NULL";
    }
    else{
      if(is_numeric ($str)){
           return $str;
      }
      else{
           return "\"".mysql_escape_string(utf8_encode($str))."\"";
      }
    }
}
```